# RSpec view specs for nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bdd

How would you write a new.html.erb_spec.rb view spec for this relationship. I am stumped.

```
  resources :things do
    resources :reviews
  end
```

Thank you.

Kent

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "reviews/new.html.erb" do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:thing,mock_model(Thing) # RSpec 2 syntax
  end

  it "shows the page" do
    render
  end
end
```

After the `render` statement add a matcher for content in the page, like:

```
rendered.should contain("some text to match")
```

Comment: Can you show how you would test for presence of forms etc, actions etc.

Comment: `render` will fail if there is no matching template file. You can also do `response.should render_template` in a controller test, which has the additional benefit of verifying that the action exists. Take a look at the spec files generated by `rails generate scaffold` -- they contain good examples for model, view, and controller specs.